# Mule - Caching Strategy - Session Clear

Tags: caching, mule

I am using Mule 3.5.0 and trying to implement the Cache Strategy. The cache is supposed to be hit by APIs for grabbing a Sugar CRM OAuth Token. Multiple endpoints are hitting this cache.

My requirement is to keep only one active element which in the queue which serves this active token to every API call for 5 minutes. When the TTL expires, the cache should grab another token and cache it for subsequent calls.

The problem arises, when multiple inbound endpoints are hitting the cache, old values are also being spit out by the cache. Is all I need to do is change the maxEntries to 1? OR is there a better way of achieving this?

```
    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
    <in-memory-store name="sugar-cache-in-memory" maxEntries="500" entryTTL="300000" expirationInterval="300000"/>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
<flow name="get-oauth-token-cache" doc:name="get-oauth-token-cache" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <ee:cache cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Cache">
    ..............................
    ..............................
    ..............................
    <logger message="------------------------ Direct Call for Token----------------------" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <DATAMAPPER to set #payload.access_token />
   </ee:cache>
   <set-session-variable variableName="access_token" value="#[payload.access_token]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in the first line after ee:cache I had the Set Payload function. Had to take it outside the Cache Scope.

Sorry.